# Why does updating a global vector with for-loop and with list comprehension in Julia give different results?

Tags: julia

I pasted the full MWE below. Since it is a bit long, I first give a break-down.

**Task:** I have a global vector `vec` that is going to be randomly updated in a loop. I have a global vector `vecvec` (vector of vectors) that is supposed to store the history of the `vec`s.

**Attempted Solution (does not work):** The function `make_vec()` randomly updates `vec`. I put this in a loop as follows.

```
for i in 1:5
    make_vec()     
    println(vec)
    push!(vecvec,vec)
end
```

Running this (or rather the MWE below), one can see from the printed output, that the global variable `vec` is updated by `make_vec()` in each round of the loop as intended. But:

**Question 1:** Why then are all vectors in the collected history `vecvec` the same?

I can guess an answer to the question, namely that `push!` does not push the actual vector `vec` but only a reference to `vec`. Thus, when I inspect `vecvec` after completion of the loop, all entries are identical to the last update of `vec`.

But this raises another question.

**Question 2:** In the MWE below, I add two alternative implementations of `make_vec()`. In particular, `make_vec2()` (`make_vec3()` is similar) is the same as `make_vec()` but replaces the for-loop with list comprehension.  Why does replacing `make_vec()` in the loop by `make_vec2()` give a different result (in fact the desired result)?

```
vec = [1,2,3]
vecvec = []

function make_vec() 
    for i in 1:3
        vec[i] = rand(0:9)
    end
end

function make2_vec()
    global vec = [rand(0:9) for i=1:3]
end

function make3_vec()
    local vec3 = [1,2,3]
    for i in 1:3
        vec3[i] = rand(0:9)
    end
    global vec = vec3
end

    
for i in 1:5
    make_vec()     # make_vec2 and make_vec3 would give the desired result, but not make_vec
    println(vec)
    push!(vecvec,vec)
end

print(vecvec)
```

I run this in a Jupyter notebook with kernel 1.8.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
    for i in 1:3
        vec[i] = rand(0:9)
    end
```

you do not change the value (array in this case) that `vec` is bound to. Instead you only change the elements stored in the array.
This is typically called in-place update.

On the other hand:

```
    global vec = [rand(0:9) for i=1:3]
```

allocates a new vector and binds this new value to `vec` variable. This means that instead of updating values in some container you replace the container.

The same with:

```
    local vec3 = [1,2,3]
    for i in 1:3
        vec3[i] = rand(0:9)
    end
    global vec = vec3
```

The `local vec3 = [1,2,3]` allocates new container and `global vec = vec3` binds this new container to `vec` variable.

Is this clear?

---

As a side note - it is better do not use `vec` as variable name as `vec` is a function name that is defined in Base Julia.

Comment: Thanks. (And, btw, also thanks for the side note, I am new to Julia.) The crucial bit of information, if I understand correctly, is that version 2 and 3 allocate a new vector, which is then stored in `vecvec` (and that `vecvec` itself does not store the `vec`s but only references to `vec`s). What happens if I create a vector of integers? Does this vector then also store references to integers or the integers themselves?

Comment: It depends how you create a vector of integers. If it is `Any[1, 2, 3]` then these are references (as such vector can store any value - like a list in Python), when you create `[1, 2, 3]` these are integers themselves. However, note that integers are not mutable so you cannot change an integer even if you have a reference to it.